# Summing Dynamically Varying Columns using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to calculate the sum of values in each column and store it in an array. Please note that the number of columns are not fixed. It varies dynamically. This is where I am totally stuck. This is just a part of a huge function I am writing.

In the below code, the "Column H" that I am summing is a variable one. I mean the number of columns to calculate sum is based on the value of Val(i).
For Eg: If Val(0) = 10, then I need to calculate sum of all numbers starting from column H till column Q, and storing sum of each column in an array, i.e.sum(0) = sum of column H; sum(1) = sum of column I; and so on.

The point where I am stuck is to increment the column, i.e. after summing "Column H" in the next iteration it should sum elements in "column I"----> (Sum(i + k) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("H2"))

I have tried something like below:

```
Dim i, j, k, l, MaxVal As Integer
Dim objNewSheet As Worksheet
Dim Sum(0 To 1000) As Double

k = 0
For i = 0 To (MaxVal-1)
    Set objNewSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet" & (i+1))
    objNewSheet.Select
    For j = 0 To Val(i)
        Sum(i + k) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("H2"))
        k = k + j
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Instead of using the `Range("H2")` syntax you'll find it easier to use something like (eg) `.Sum(objNewSheet.Cells(2,8).Resize(1,10))` Using `Resize(numRow, numCols)` is the easiest way to extend a range to a specific number of rows/columns.

Comment: Why do you `Dim Sum(0 to 1000)`? assuming there will be a dynamic number of columns to store in this array, you may prefer another method to build the array dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim mentions, you can use the `Resize` method to modify the size of your Range.

```
Dim rng as Range: Set rng = Range("H2")
Sum(i + k) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng.Resize(1, j))
```

The above should create a new range that is `j` columns wide.

I add a `Range` variable because they are easier to work with (IMO) that the constants like `Range("H2")`.  You can use `MsgBox rng.Resize(1,j).Address` to view the new range's address.

Here are a few other points you may want to consider:

- You have not declared your variables correctly, unless you truly
  intend for `i, j, k, l as Variant`. You could do:

  `Dim i#, j#, k#, l#, MaxValue#` (shorthand notation) or

  `Dim i as Integer, j as Integer, k as Integer, l as Integer, MaxValue as Integer`

  Otherwise, unless you specify a type for each variable, they will be Variant.
- For readability, you may want to avoid naming variables after reserved or semi-reserved keywords or existing functions like `Sum`. I would rename that variable to `mySum` or `sumArray` or something else which will obviously indicate to future users that this is a variable, not a function.
- I mention in my comment above that initially dimensioning your array variable with an upper-bound of 1000 is kind of clunky, and will obviously fail if you ever encounter a need for a larger array. This may not be the case, but it's still a clunky way of dimensioning an array.  I would suggest `Dim mySum() as Double` and then `ReDim` the variable later in the code, perhaps using `ReDim Preserve` if it needs to be truly dynamic at run-time.

**UPDATE**

Here is a simple example, your code is only a snippet/incomplete, so I cannot use it, but this example should illustrate how this works.

```
Option Base 1
Sub Test()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim mySum() As Double

    '## The initial range ##'
    Set rng = Range("H2")

    '## Do an iterative loop ##'
    For i = 1 To 4

        '## Resize the range within the iteration ##'
        Set rng = rng.Resize(1, i)  '<-- change the 1 in this line to the number of rows in the column that needs to be summed'
        '## Ensure the array is properly dimensioned ##'
        ReDim Preserve mySum(i)
        '## Store the calculation in the array ##'
        mySum(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for all of your efforts. Since I am new to VBA, I am not aware of all the functions like Resize. All suggentions accepted. Thanks again

Comment: I used the method suggested by you, but it is not working. I ean I am not getting the sum in mySum() array. Not able to find the reason behind it. I have a question here: Does the code you suggested calculates the sum of all numbers in column H and in next iteration calculates sum of all numbers in column I and so on?                        
    Dim rng as Range: Set rng = Range("H2")
mySum(i + k) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng.Resize(1, j))

Comment: No, this calculates the sum of cells in `H2`, `H2:I2`, `H2:J2`, etc.  There is no indication anywhere in your code about how many rows to include. But that could be done easily enough.

Comment: See revision with an example for you to try out. Obviously, I can't do much since your code is not complete enough for me to replicate/use, but I created a small example that you should be able to modify.  Cheers.